# Where does PHP get its $PATH from?

Tags: php, macos, shell, path

Trying to execute a shell command through PHP

In terminal, if I use `echo $PATH` I get my full path which i've set to `/Users/edward/.composer/vendor/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin`

In PHP `get_current_user()` gives me the same user I am logged in with on the above terminal which is `edward`

However if I run `shell_exec('echo $PATH')` I only get `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` which is a problem for me because I am trying to use `shell_exec()` to run a command which it can't find, given that `$PATH`

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.4 with apache2 and PHP 5.6.
Adding to `$PATH` in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` does not seem to have any effect.

P.S. I am aware I can solve this by simply using the full path to the executable in my `shell_exec()` call but I develop on a Mac system and deploy to a linux system and the paths are not the same, so I'd rather just fix my `$PATH`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP system calls and $PATH in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431858/php-system-calls-and-path-in-os-x)

Comment: Keep in mind, that cli php can have (so imho by default) his own php.ini ...

Comment: If you `shell_exec("id -un")` may indicate who the path belongs to. (I am given to understand that `id -un` is the OSX equivalent to the *NIX `whoami`)

Answer (score 0):

Its coming from $_SERVER["PATH"] when you run it on browser (served via apache). Its going to be different than "echo $PATH" when "you" (edward) runs it on shell terminal. The apache webserver would be running with 'apache' or 'httpd' user permission. The "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" is the value of $PATH for apache server user.

You might want to see: http://php.net/putenv & http://php.net/apache_setenv

Side note: In case you plan to use this on production, using getenv('PATH') would be much elegant rather than shell_exec('echo $PATH').

Comment: As I wrote in my post "In PHP get_current_user() gives me the same user I am logged in with on the above terminal which is edward" and I am not running PHP inside a browser (that doesn't even make sense to me)

Comment: `get_current_user()` returns the name of the owner of the current PHP script]  and thus might not be of relevance here. cf. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Comment: As mentioned in [PHP system calls and $PATH in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431858/php-system-calls-and-path-in-os-x), is ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist in sync with what is set in .profile ?

Comment: @Ashish-G I don't have that file, but the relevant bit I need and was missing is `/usr/local/bin` which I did not set that inside my `.profile`. It must be part of the default path?

Comment: @Dwardu - yes, lets update PATH into .profile with /usr/local/bin & check. If that doesn't work, you can set PATH in beginning of your script using http://php.net/putenv (or http://php.net/apache_setenv for browser flow) to ensure required PATH value during script execution.

Comment: @Ashish-G I already have other sections being appended to path in `.profile` which do not get added for PHP, and I do not want to add code just to support my local environment. I just want my `$PATH` to match my users when using `shell_exec()` right off the bat