# PHP script not executing pdflatex

Tags: php, unix, pdflatex

I have a PHP script which accepts data from an incoming POST request, downloads the data to a file, and then runs a shell script.  Only some parts of the shells script are executed --- don't know why.  The request is

```
https://knode.work/processLatex.php
```

where the body is the JSON `{data: SOURCE}` and SOURCE is LaTeX source text.  Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php
$post_data = $_POST['data'];
if (!empty($post_data)) {
    $dir = '/var/www/html/files/';
    $file = 'foo';
    $filename = $dir.$file.'.tex';
    $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $post_data);
    fclose($handle);
    chdir($dir);
    exec("sh texit.sh");
    echo("Done!!");
}
?>
```

And here is the shell script:

```
/usr/bin/pdflatex foo.tex
/usr/bin/pdfatex foo.tex
rm yuuk.txt
rm *.out *.log *.aux
```

The `/usr/bin/pdflatex` lines are not executed, but the other lines are.  What the heck?  Are not all lines equal?

((Could there be a permissions problem?))

Below is a listing of the `./files` directory.  I created `foo.pdf` by running `pdflatex foo.tex` as root.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     207383 Aug 13 17:31 foo.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  11372 Aug 13 18:35 foo.tex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         84 Aug 13 17:40 texit.sh
```

So perhaps the problem lies in the ownership of `foo.tex` versus that of `pdflatex` (re comment below) by RiggsFolly.  Here is the dope on `pdflatex`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Aug 21  2017 /usr/bin/pdflatex -> pdftex
```

Also, I set everything up as `root`, e.g.,

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 13 18:36 html
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is all that accessible by your web server account? Probably acccount `www` and not your user account

Comment: How would I check accessibility by `www`?  I'm really new at this stuff.  I tried `su www pdflatex foo.tex` but got: "No password entry for this user."

Comment: Isn't the `texit.sh` file supposed to have a header like `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Anyway, pretty sure the problem is related to not having the correct environment variables to load `/usr/bin/pdflatex` successfully, try setting `PATH` in your .sh file to something that makes sense (copy the one you have in terminal) and see if the command works.

Comment: It should indeed.  I made that change, but it had no effect on the outcome.  (I think this matters only if the script is run as `./texit.sh` -- I am running it as `sh texit.sh`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431858/php-system-calls-and-path-in-os-x

Comment: i am using full paths, as in `/usr/bin/pdflatex foo.tex` -- so is the `PATH` setting needed in this case? (Noob question).  Aslo, this is running under Ubuntu 18.* --- don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Here is the info on `PATH`:

`root@knodeWorker:/var/www/html/files# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

So it looks like there is access to `/usr/bin/pdfaltex`

Comment: You have access to `/usr/bin/pdfaltex` but there's no telling if `/usr/bin/pdfaltex` has access to it's dependencies. Change your .sh script to set `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` to mimic what you have in the shell and see if it works.

Comment: Maybe there are other relevant env vars too but usually `PATH` is the guilty one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177971/discussion-between-epsilon2-7-and-havenard).

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, it really helped me.